# Can Someone Combine these 2 scripts

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

Can't get this to work.  The first part is a toggle function (mouse button 8) which functions with the use of mouse button 1 being pressed and released. The second part (mouse button 7) is just a "click to use" functionality.

I can flip flop these parts, and only the second part works, which makes me confused.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
        if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
            EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
        elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
            ReleaseMouseButton(2) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
        end
        if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 8) then
            recoil = not recoil
            spot = not spot
        end
        if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil) then
            if recoil then
                repeat
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 23)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 24)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 21)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 23)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 27)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 26)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 25)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end
        end
    end
```

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7) then
        MoveMouseTo(39805, 60267)
        Sleep(30)
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(50)
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(50)
        MoveMouseTo(32805, 50267)
        Sleep(25)
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(30)
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    end
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `either one code or the other works, not both` - what do you mean?  Do you want to press G7 while LMB is down?

Comment: So I guess the correct answer is, I am not sure how to combine them.  If I put both scripts, as is, in the same file, It is always the second script that works, and never the first one.  I need both of them to work in the same script, as my mouse will only run one script at a time. Script one is labled "no recoil" and script two is "character select" - I can only run one at a time currently, I would like to combine them into "game script" so both are active at the same time.

Comment: Indent your scripts correctly, and you will easily see where to insert additional "if" in the first script.

Comment: I edited the original post to show the code that I updated to with the indentations. I still have the same issue, in that when the 7th mouse button is pushed, the corresponding code runs, but nothing happens with the first set for the 8th mouse button.  I clearly am missing something, but I cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
        if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
            EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
        elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
            ReleaseMouseButton(2) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
        end
        if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 8) then
            recoil = not recoil
            spot = not spot
        end
        if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil) then
            if recoil then
                repeat
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 23)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 24)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 21)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 23)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 27)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 26)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-1, 25)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(16, 4)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                MoveMouseRelative(-16, 0)
                Sleep(100) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end

    elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7) then
        MoveMouseTo(16000, 61000)
        Sleep(30)
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(50)
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(50)
        MoveMouseTo(32805, 50267)
        Sleep(25)
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(30)
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    end
end
```